# send a request to wbservice without redirect in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, redirect

I am using a url to send sms in my website as you can see here :

```
http://37.130.202.188/class/sms/webservice/send_url.php?from=50005150149148&to=09120838238&msg=Hi&uname=*****&pass=****
```

But i need to send my request to send the sms without redirect .how can i do that?I used `response.redirect` but it caused to redirect .!!!

I don't need any redirect in my website because after sending the sms i do other operations.

i am using c# -asp.net
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

1) Using `WebClient`:

```
String response = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(YOUR_URL);
```

2) Using `HttpWebRequest`:

```
string _url = "http://37.130.202.188/class/sms/webservice/send_url.php?from=50005150149148&to=09120838238&msg=Hi&uname=*****&pass=****";

string _respose = GetResponse(_url);

public string GetResponse(string sURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL); request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8); string sResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
        return sResponse;
    }
    catch
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "There might be an Internet connection issue..";
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer.. @EhsanAkbar